# Trying to get Grails SSC AJAX login to work with Chrome extension

Tags: grails, spring-security, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that will login to my Grails application using the Spring Security Core plugin's AJAX abilities. If there was no previous login and I login from the extension (ajax), it works. Then if I logout (ajax), that works as well, but any further logins (ajax) fail but I get an ajax success telling me the username is anonymousUser.

In order to reset things, I need to login/logout through the standard web login (non-ajax) and I can once again login/logout once using ajax. Then I get the anonymousUser username again.

How can I troubleshoot this, or get the Grails security to clear the username like the normal non-ajax login/logout?

Is it perhaps something related to Chrome?

Comment: Adding some more debug code, I'm noticing that my sessionId of the authentication object is null after the ajax logout vs the normal web logout. Might that be my problem?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be Chrome, as it seems when I look at the cookies, the extension is not updating them like the response says too. So I've got an old jsessionid value which I'm guessing Spring Security doesn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a problem with the cookie security within Chrome. I'm still working on trying to figure out the specifics but to get around it, I had to set the jsessionid cookie explicitly in the extension code. It would seem to me that if I had the permissions set to allow XHR requests that those permissions should also be applied to the cookies.